# h:inputtext enable/disable from class

Tags: jsf

hi as per my requirement there is one h:inputtext to find user. If user is found it populated first name, last name and email in corresponding h:inputtext which is disabled. but if not found that inputtext should become enabled and new details can be filled.

```
<h:inputText value="#{countryBean.usersDetailsDTO.eid}" id="eid" required="true"       requiredMessage="Enter EID">

            <f:ajax></f:ajax>
        </h:inputText><h:message styleClass="msgStyle4" id="msgEid" for="eid"/>
    </div>
    <h:commandButton  styleClass="search_btn"   immediate="true">
        <f:ajax listener="#{countryBean.getUserDetail}" render="empFName empLName empEmail" event="click" execute="@this" />
    </h:commandButton>
    <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>

    <div class="form-field" style="margin-left:222px;">
        first Name  <h:inputText value="#{countryBean.usersDetailsDTO.firstName}" id="empFName" required="true" requiredMessage="Enter First Name">
        <f:validator validatorId="nameValidation" />
        </h:inputText><h:message styleClass="msgStyle4" id="msgfn" for="empFName"/>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="form-field" style="margin-left:10px;">
        last name  <h:inputText value="#{countryBean.usersDetailsDTO.lastName}" id="empLName" required="true" requiredMessage="Enter Last Name">
        <f:validator validatorId="nameValidation" />
        </h:inputText><h:message styleClass="msgStyle4"  id="msgln" for="empLName"/>
    </div><div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="form-field" style="margin-left:10px;">
        email<h:inputText value="#{countryBean.usersDetailsDTO.email}" id="empEmail" required="true" requiredMessage="Enter Email Address">
        <f:validator validatorId="emailValidation" />
        </h:inputText><h:message styleClass="msgStyle4"  id="msgEmail" for="empEmail"/>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `disabled` attribute on any time along with JSF EL to pass the Boolean value to `disabled` attribute.
For example in your case  If you want to disable any `h:inputText` if first name is pre-populated then:

```
<h:inputText value="#{countryBean.usersDetailsDTO.email}" id="empEmail"     
required="true" requiredMessage="Enter Email Address"      
disabled="#{not(empty countryBean.usersDetailsDTO.firstName)}">
```

The above code will disable the `Email` input text `disabled` if `firstname` is pre-populated.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this on 2 ways:

1) You set the disable-tag of the inputText to a BackingBean-method like this:

```
<h:inputText ... disabled="#{countryBean.found}" ... />
```

2) Adding a valueChangeListener on the first inputText, so if it has a text, the others should be disabled.